# how to split a string into substring using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string like this 'dubai,sharjah,' and I want to make it like this 'dubai','sharja',

I am passing the value dubai,sharjah, in the URL using ajax and `my code`

```
$city=$_GET['city'];

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM filter where isdeleted = 0 ";

if ($city !="" && $city !="Empty" ){
     $sql.=" and twon in ('".$citydata."')";                  
}
```

when I print the query, it's like this

```
SELECT * FROM filter where isdeleted = 0 and twon in ('dubai,sharjah,')
```

but I want it like this

```
SELECT * FROM filter where isdeleted = 0 and twon in ('dubai','sharja')
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do this using PHP?

Comment: Where are you getting `$citydata`

Comment: If you're trying to generate a sql query that you'll actually use to run a query, I'm going to suggest you stop right there and read this on how to use bind variables: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php Better to protect yourself from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: `$sql.=" and twon in ('".str_replace(",","','",$citydata)."')";`

Comment: @GarySchreiner `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` is a nightmare when dealing with an array of values. I recommend PDO for this type of thing.

Comment: @Phil I agree, was just trying to get prepared statements across in a hurry before 10 answers showed up :) As I mentioned on a comment to your answer, I find your solution the best option. Unfortunately edit window on comments only last for 5 minutes.

Comment: [Explode on commas and use a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036322/2943403)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if ($city !="" && $city !="Empty" )
{
     $city_exp = explode(',' $city);
     $sql .= " and twon in ('".implode("', '", $city_exp)."')"; 
}
```

What we are basically doing here is putting the two values in an array by using `explode` and then separating each item in that array by using `implode`

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pZUvev)

Comment: Doesn't work so well if one of the cities is *Sha'am* or similar ~ http://codepad.viper-7.com/r5F0bi

Comment: The value is coming from the URL query string. It could be anything

Comment: This answer encourages poor practices in regards to interacting with databases via PHP. You should be using prepared statements as per the answer by @Phil

Comment: @Alex.Ritna You're right. But I don't think the OP will make an effort to switch over to PDO/mysqli.

Comment: @asprin IMHO, SO isn't just for the OP, but also for everyone else who finds this question & answer on Google. Maybe a good edit would be: "While this answers your question, here's a better way of doing it that won't be susceptible to attacks." I bet most people searching for something like this probably never would have heard about prepared statements, and this would be their first hint at them.

Comment: @Alex.Ritna In fairness, [Mikk3lRo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23646581/283366) also addresses the SQL injection vector though it does use the deprecated *mysql* extension.

Comment: @Phil Correct. Neither this answer or the one by Mikk3lRo are the best answer in addressing the question **and** promoting good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would approach it. I'm going to use PDO instead of *mysqli* because trying to get an array into `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` is just a pain.

First, create an array of cities, removing any empty values

```
$params = array_filter(explode(',', $city), function($c) {
    return !empty($c) && $c !== 'Empty';
});
$paramCount = count($params);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM filter where isdeleted = 0';
```

Now generate a placeholder string for your prepared statement.

```
if ($paramCount) {
    $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, $paramCount, '?');
    // looks something like '?,?'

    $query .= " AND twon IN ($placeholders)";
}
```

Now, prepare a statement

```
// assuming you have a PDO instance in $pdo created with something like
// $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
```

Execute and fetch values :)

```
$stmt->execute($params);
$filters = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$cities = explode(",", $_GET['city']);

//escape!
foreach ($cities as $citykey => $city) {
    $cities[$citykey] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($city) . "'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `filter` where `isdeleted` = 0";
if (!empty($cities)) {
    $sql .= ' and `twon` in (' . implode(',', $cities) . ')';
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the *mysql* extension has been officially deprecated and is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). No PHP code change needed.

```
$sql.=" and FIND_IN_SET(town, '".$citydata."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to explode and implode here. Rest is the problem with extra `,` in your string at the end.

```
$str = "dubai,sharjah,";
$citydata = implode("','",explode(',',rtrim($str,',')));
echo "'$citydata'";
```

[test](http://ideone.com/5OFTDn)

Answer (score 1):

After 6 answers I gotta add a 7th:

```
$sql.=" and twon in ('".str_replace(",","','",$citydata)."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to explode the string

```
$cityparts = explode(",",$city);
```

and you can use

```
$cityparts[0] and $cityparts[1] in your query 

array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

you can find more information on [[http://www.php.net/explode]](http://www.php.net/explode%5d)

hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
$string = 'dubai,sharjah';
$cities = explode(',', $string);

echo $cities[0]; //dubai
echo $cities[1]; //sharjah
```

Comment: this will print `"dubaisharjah"`, not `"dubai", "sharjah"`. This might be better: `echo $cities[0].", ".$cities[1]`

Comment: @YUNOWORK "twon in ($cities[0], $cities[1])"  Isn't it obivious?

Comment: For me it wasnt, but its still early in the morning, i shouldnt suggest improvements before 8:00 AM. :s

Comment: question not want to print .He only want to pass as an array

Comment: @YUNOWORK We've all been there.

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal Have you read the question? Where does it say pass an array? Does mysql "in" work on an array?

Comment: @Jay Bhatt Using get he get the value in different format.he want to just convert it to pass as an arguement for IN

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal "twon in ($cities[0], $cities[1])" And how is this different from what your saying?

Comment: @Jay Bhatt this is not dynamic. in case he has 3 city then add another $cities[2] and so on

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal I don't assume stuff. Has the user asked for it in the question?

Comment: @Jay Bhatt thats ur mistake. you misunderstand that question. The exact anwers posted already

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal So not assuming things is a mistake? Wow never knew that. Anyway this is going to far now. I'll leave you now.

Comment: @Jay Bhatt the question exactly want to change the format of an array to make suitable to pass to IN.In your answer you just explode it and echo it.ie you are in halfway mark.Not satisfy the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$str = "dubai,sharjah,";
$arr = explode(",", $str);
$arr_temp = array()
foreach($arr as $s)
{
   if($s!="")
   {
      $arr_temp[] = "'".$s."'";
   }
}

$new_str = implode(",", $arr_temp); 
echo $new_str;  // output 'dubai','sharjah'
```

Now your Sql will be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM filter where isdeleted = 0 and twon in ($new_str) ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it
in `$city` I fix two values with, you can use here by `$_GET` ;

```
$city = "dubai,sharjah,";
$query_string ="";
$words = explode(",",$city);
for($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++){$query_string .= "'".$words[$i]."',";}
$query_string = substr($query_string,0,strlen($query_string)-4);
```

then use your query

```
SELECT * FROM filter where isdeleted = 0 and twon in ($query_string)
```